# Is this variable just a string of numbers?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want a code to specify which variables in a dictionary like the following ***are not*** just a string of numbers?

```
myDictionary = {
'first' : '2345687554',
'second' : 'fgdjsa87gh',
'third' : '87hfkd77d'
}
```

In fact, I wrote a function that takes a number of usernames and passwords as arguments and returns the names that qualify in a list:

```
def check_registration_rules (**x):   
mylist = []
for usname in x.keys():
    if (len(usname) >= 4) and (usname != 'quera' and usname != 'codecup') and (len(x[usname]) >= 6 ):
        mylist.append(usname)
return mylist
```

But it is necessary to find out whether the password of a username is just a string of numbers or not. If it is a string of numbers, it does not have the necessary conditions.
I did not find a solution to this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear so I won't even try to answer it, but even if it _were_ clear we're not here to write code for you. "I want code" is not what this place is about.

Comment: Python strings have an [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method that will return `True` if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character. `{k: v.isdigit() for k, v in myDictionary.items()}` will tell you which values are all digits. You can put `not` in front to get the opposite.

Comment: More generally, open an interactive session and type `help(str)` and you'll find the keys to the kingdom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Python` you can check if a `str`ing is made out of only digits with [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

```
>>> "42".isdigit()
True
>>> "53SS0".isdigit()
False
```

In your case something like this should work:

```
if (not usname.isdigit()):
    ...
```